# What is this "should"?

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives, subordinate-clauses

> I'd rather do it myself than that my subordinate should do it.

What is this "should"? Is this the same as would as in subjunctive?

Comment: Yes, it's almost the same but more expressive.

Comment: The sentence is not grammatical. You can't use should like that.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* may imply his own expectation on his subordinates.

I haven't read "A Colossal Battle" by Walter J. Manning, so this could be wrong. But I guess this sentence states that this person prioritizes his will before others', that he takes his own decisions no matter what, even when these decisions mean he will suffer, even die!, before letting others take the decisions on his behalf.

And beyond that, the sentence implies that he expects the same from his subordinates. He wants his subordinates to take decisions, to act, because (I assume) if they don't then they are forcing others to decide/act on their behalf, to take decisions and actions for them.

I guess the sentence may be aluding to the known, very human 'fight', between taking charge of our own life, and taking care of others. If this is the context of the sentence, then the author wants this person to illustrate how far he'll go to take charge of his: well beyond others' well being and even his own.

He wants to depict a 'brave' person (he chooses his destiny, not others!). "Would" would depict a more 'coward' person (he reacts to others' actions). I use brave and coward as to how this person would see himself, not my opinion of course.

(I guess I've gone too far in the answer. Just guessing. I just hope it helps clarify the meaning and why using *should* instead of *would*).